# Getting class, interface or enum expected error in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

So I'm fairly new to JSP but I keep getting the class, interface or enum expected error in jsp.

Do I have to nest the scriptlet within the declaration itself?

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%! 
            PreparedStatement psmt;
            Connection con;
             public void jspInit(){
                try{
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JSPData?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root","root");
                psmt = con.prepareStatement("Insert into jspData Values(?,?,?)");

                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        %>
        <%!
           String uname;
           String pwd;
           String email;%>

        <% 
            uname= request.getParameter("uname");
            pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
            email=request.getParameter("email");

            psmt.setString(1,uname);
            psmt.setString(2,pwd);
            psmt.setString(3,email);
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
           out.println("<h2>Record Inserted</h2>");
            }
        %>

        <%! 
            public void jspDestroy() {
                try {
                    con.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

More specifically I am getting those errors in this bit of my code:

```
    pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
    email=request.getParameter("email");

    psmt.setString(1,uname);
    psmt.setString(2,pwd);
    psmt.setString(3,email);
    int i=stmt.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0){
   out.println("<h2>Record Inserted</h2>");
    }
```

I especially do not understand why I'm not getting the error the `uname= request.getParameter("uname");` line but I am getting it at the similar initializations of password and email below it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using scriptlets at all.

Comment: How come? Wouldn't the non-declaration code go in a scriptlet? What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should be using [model 2](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076557/java-web-development/understanding-javaserver-pages-model-2-architecture.html). Scriptlets are model 1 technology (especially to make **DB calls**). And yes, that article on model 2 is from **1999**.

Comment: and even in proper java coding `catch(Exception e){}` - never swallow excpetions